# Consuming External Rest API in apex

Tags: rest-api, httprequest, http

I have a requirement where I have to consume external REST API. I have the URL for the same and the values for the parameters to be passed to get a response XML from the service. I am not getting how to pass these parameters to the URL. I have to pass the apiKey, AccountId etc etc to get a response XML. I am pretty new to HttpCallouts so please help me in this regard.

Comment: Are you able to hit the API from a client such as cURL and get a response?

Comment: Yes I was able to successfully test the API using SoapUI and I got the response back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to setting the URL parameters. I set the paramaters in `req.setBody('key1=value1&key2=value2');`

I was able to finally make the call through the MockCallout by passing the method input parameter.

Comment: This will work for post methods. If you want to pass parameters in the request for GET method then you can append the url request by the parameters to be sent.
For example:  
https://testrequest.com is your api then
https://testrequest.com?Accountname=testAccountName will be the parameter url

Comment: Thanks @krishsfdc for the suggestion. It supports both GET and POST methods but set the Method as POST.